# What does one need to deal with or know when working with dates and times?

Tags: datetime

Around the internet I've found a lot of little tricks that slip up programmers when working with dates and times.

Some examples include:

- Not all timezones are whole numbers
- The 100/400 rule with regards to leap years
- dd/mm/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy
- The 2038 problem
- etc

So what should a programmer dealing with dates and times know? Please keep each piece of information in its own answer.

What issues are involved when dealing with timezones? Differing days around the world. Etc etc etc.

I am not looking for trite answers "using the existing" functions because that answers precisely nothing. It does not tell me what issues are involved when writing a time heavy application (say a calendar)